# can any one suggest me the reference for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

Hi guys I want some references which can answer questions like

how table is parsed, how where condition is checked against each row, same goes for inner joins how sql performs inner join , what happens when you say ON , inner join where,  left join, coorelated subqueries, subquery how they work.

specific to sqlite3

Comment: You can't just ask for references! you should google it.

Comment: I googled but dint find any good references, you'll can even suggest good books

Comment: Suggesting off site resources is explicitly off topic for this website.

Answer (score 0):

While this is technically incorrect use of the forum try:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm